# db.loadServerScripts() from mongodb shell?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to run db.loadServerScripts() from mongodb shell?
I have stored this:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

```
db.system.js.insertOne(
   {
     _id : "myAddFunction" ,
     value : function (x, y){ return x + y; }
   }
);
```

But when I run db.loadServerScripts() from the shell the function isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem; by chance, are you using the new "mongosh"? If so, that tool does not support db.loadServerScripts() yet (don't know if it ever will); one alternative would be to have a copy of those custom scripts on a file that you could load before executing other commands.